# Google Cloud Dataflow Worker Threading

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Say we have one worker with 4 CPU cores. How does parallelism configured in Dataflow worker machines? Do we parallelize beyond # of cores?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I also previously thought that the dataflow workers used 1 thread per core. However, I have recently found out that this is only true for batch mode. In streaming mode, unless otherwise specified it uses 300 threads as seen [here](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/6fdde4f4eab72b49b10a8bb1cb3be263c5c416b5/runners/google-cloud-dataflow-java/worker/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/runners/dataflow/worker/StreamingDataflowWorker.java#L741). This is in contrast to the [batch worker code](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/fd946acdd035fd10914ea6eab18752e61afceb41/runners/google-cloud-dataflow-java/worker/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/runners/dataflow/worker/DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java#L95). To restrict the number of worker threads, use `--numberOfWorkerHarnessThreads=N`.

My story of how I found this out:
I had a streaming job with a ParDo that would read XML files and parse them. The workers ran out of memory because they tried to chew on too many files at once. I used a static AtomicInteger to count the number of concurrent executions of my ParDo. Also, I logged the threadIds used to execute my ParDo. I could see as many as 300 concurrent executions on one worker, and the number of different threadIds logged also indicated that the worker was using a large number of threads.

I fixed my memory issues by restricting the number of threads used with `--numberOfWorkerHarnessThreads=10`. I also tried setting that number to 1 thread, but that seemed to result in only one pipeline step being executed at any given time. Not surprising, but I wanted a higher level of parallelism, so 10 seemed like a good number for my use-case.

**Edit**: Added some extra information. Thanks to @safurudin-mahic for finding the relevant Beam source code.

Comment: The python variant of this flag is `--number_of_worker_harness_threads`

Answer (score 1):

For batch jobs, one worker thread is used per core, and each worker thread independently processes a chunk of the input space.

For streaming jobs, there can be many more worker threads per core to wait on input.

Comment: So 1 machine with 4 core, parallelism is 4? Thanks

Comment: Also, can we find this information somewhere in the documentation? Would be super helpful.

Comment: I came across this while looking or an answer for my own slightly different question. Can you please clarify if there is a difference between running a DataFlow job locally on, say, a Compute Engine instance with 8 CPUs, vs. running it remotely on 8 N1-standard-1 DataFlow workers? Obviously Auto-Scaling is one difference, but are there any advantages or disadvantages for local vs. remote otherwise? Especially as relates to parallel processing. Thanks!

Comment: @VS_FF: The local runner is mostly intended for experimenting and debugging, and has not been as heavily optimized. Besides not being able to use auto-scaling, it performs more operations in memory (like shuffle) and would not scale to nearly as large datasets.

Comment: this answer is not correct for streaming jobs and also it is missing some reference link

Comment: The reference link is: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/resources/faq#how_many_instances_of_dofn_should_i_expect_dataflow_to_spin_up_